# Dotnet Core - Get the application's launch path

Tags: linux, .net-core, dotnet-cli

**Question - Is there a better/right way to get the application's launch path?**

**Setup -**
I have a console application that runs in a Linux Debian docker image. I am building the application using the `--runtime linux-x64` command line switch and have all the runtime identifiers set appropriately. I was expecting the application to behave the same whether launching it by calling `dotnet MyApplication.dll` or `./MyApplication` but they are not.

**Culprit Code -**
I have deployed files in a folder below the application directory that I reference so I do the following to get what I consider my launch path. I have read various articles saying this is the correct way to get what I want, and it works depending on how I launch it.

```
using var processModule = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;
var basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(processModule?.FileName);
```

When launching this using the comand `dotnet MyApplication.dll` the above codes path is `/usr/share/dotnet`

When launching this using the command `./MyApplication.dll` the path is then `/app`

I understand why using `dotnet` would be different as it is the process that is running my code, but again it was unexpected.

Any help here to what I should use given the current environment would be appreciated. Ultimately I need the path where the console application started from as gathered by the application when it starts up.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```
public static IConfiguration LoadConfiguration()
{
       var assemblyDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
.....

}
```